# Group - Added (by Email) - how do i prevent this?

Tags: civimail, groups, bounce

I have a contact which is a member of 2 groups and the status is "Added (by Email)" - i don't want this to be possible!

on the same day, the account i use for bulk email received a (no subject) email from the relevant contact to civimail+u.1421.81227.ac26f752ec18f10b@

The IDs of the groups in question are 14 and 10.

in civimail accounts i have a default "bounce processing" with localpart "civimail+" account which i understand is for all bulk sending.

I also have one without a localpart used for "email-to-activity" - i don't think i actually want this at all now i look, but it's there currently.

What is triggering the "added (by email)" group join, and how can i block it in the future?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the 'Added (by Email)' is actually how they were added? It could be that status is wrong / misleading rather than something incorrect is happening

Comment: I'm not certain, no - i'll do some more testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added (by Email) is normally added when a contact is added to the group using a subscription URL provided in any mail.

It is basically used to know how a contact was added to the group.  This information is stored in `civicrm_subscription_history` table(`method` column) in civicrm database.

If you want to simply remove `Email` method from your DB, you can do it by a simple SQL -

```
UPDATE civicrm_subscription_history SET method = 'Web' WHERE method = 'Email'
```

To avoid it in future, you can proceed in writing an extension and a post hook which updates `civicrm_subscription_history` after a group contact is created.